# VBA Macro to add a blank line before a header number in Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

Fairly experienced Excel VBA coder, newbie for Word macros.

I have a Word 2013 document output with almost 300 numbered paragraphs that all run together with minimal formatting. The paragraph numbers all start in column 1, with the whole text paragraph shifted over one tab of 5 spaces, until the next number which is back in column 1 and so on. No blank lines until the end of the document.

Is there a way to write a macro that cycles through the entire document, and if it finds a number in column 1, that it then adds a blank line before it?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are the numbers actual bullets?

Comment: No bullets, just numbering starting with 1. and a heading, then the text as an indented  paragraph, followed by 2. and a heading, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand your document looks like this:

```
1     Heading
test test test
2     Other heading
test test test
test 33test test
test test test2
test test test
test 44 test test
test test test
3     Other heading
```

And you would like to have it like this:

```
. <- would represent a empty line 
1     Heading
test test test

2     Other heading
test test test
test 33test test
test test test2
test test test
test 44test test
test test test

3     Other heading
```

In such a case you won't need a macro. You could use the `Search and Replace` option of Microsoft Word and some `Wildcard` magic.

Use Search Replace with the option `Use wildcards` activated

- Search for: **[^11-^13](<[0-9]>)**
- Replace with: **^13^13\1**

Breakdown:

```
[^11-^13](<[0-9]>)

^11       = Shift-Enter (New line)
^13       = Enter (Paragrah)
[]        = Marks the range of the two characters
[^11-^13] = Will find any Shift-Enter or Enter character
()        = Marks a group
<>        = Marks the start and end of a word
[0-9]     = Will find a single character 0-9

^13^13\1

^13 = inserts a paragraph
\1  = inserts the group marked in the search string
```

For more information on how to use this feature look at this page: http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working on this solution. At first try it fails, as there are numerals in the text as well that it's picking up. Is there a way to specify a numeral at the beginning of a line or restricted to columns 1-2?

Comment: I've updated my answer according your new requirement. The very first header won't work with this approach. I guess this still would be a feasible solution.